# How to redirect an url with language code to base url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

If the URL contains a language code, like `example.com/en`, I'd like something in my `.htaccess` file to redirect it to my base URL, `example.com`.

It's a WordPress site. Now I have this in my `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase  /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


</IfModule>
```

So, what I basically need is `example.com/en` -> `example.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have unnecessary code duplication in your `.htaccess` file. Consequently, the second code block isn't doing anything.

You should also avoid editing the directives within the WordPress code-block (the *front-controller*) since this is likely to be overridden by WordPress (which might explain why you've duplicated the code?!

If you simply want to redirect the URL `example.com/en` to `example.com/` - as stated - then format your `.htaccess` file like this:

```
# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Redirect /en to root
RewriteRule ^en$ / [R=302,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase  /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```